# ObjFile.Name not comapring with String in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

i have a variable String named fileName and another variable named finalDoc
i am trying to compare both but it is not working. the program does not go in the if condition

```
Dim fileName As String


fileName = objFile.Name
finalDoc = cellValue & "-" & Range(sheetNo).Value & ".pdf"
//The fileName and finalDoc are getting values as expected

 If finalDoc = fileName Then
                            'MsgBox finalDoc & " " & fileName

 End If
```

the if condition is not working. it only works if i hardcode the value in fileName like

```
 fileName ="abc.pdf"
```

any suggestions, i think this is a type issue String etc. Any help would be appreciated.
Using VBA of Excel 2013

Comment: what's the value of `fileName` and whats the value of `finalDoc` when you are comparing it? Have you tried using `StrComp()` function with `vbTextCompare` parameter?

Comment: Comparing strings can be tricky. I am not surr what kind of object objfile is but  try the common way of comparing sting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @ruedi the link is for Visual Basic not VBA and it's I think a German version :P

Comment: Here's the [StrComp() in VBA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx)

Comment: Or convert both: `If LCase$(finalDoc) = LCase$(fileName) Then`

Comment: And make sure you don't have white spaces in the strings.. `Trim(finalDoc)`

Comment: the value coming in fileName is abc.pdf   and the value coming in finalDoc is abc.pdf i have seen it by MsgBox. Will try Trim function and see if it works.

Comment: And you can also use `like` operator to do the comparison...

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a string using "=". You must use the StrComp command that will return an integer depending on the outcome.

More information can be found [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx)

But here is an example that returns a match when comparing ABC.pdf and abc.pdf:

```
Sub test1()

Dim fileName1 As String
Dim fileName2 As String
Dim TestComp As Integer

fileName1 = "abc.pdf"
fileName2 = "ABC.pdf"

TestComp = StrComp(fileName1, fileName2, vbTextCompare)

If TestComp = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Match!")
    Else
    MsgBox (fileName1 & " and " & fileName2 & " are No Match. Outcome is " & TestComp)
End If

End Sub
```

All you now need to do is adjust this code to suit your needs.

Basically:

```
Dim fileName As String
Dim TestComp As Integer


fileName = objFile.Name
finalDoc = cellValue & "-" & Range(sheetNo).Value & ".pdf"

TestComp = StrComp(fileName,finalDoc,vbTextCompare)

If TestComp = 0 Then
        //Insert code to run for a correct match
Else
        //Insert code to run for incorrect match

End If
```